# Observable - debounceTime for http service doesn't work - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

just a simple question but I can't make it work :( How to combine debounceTime with the http service?

So I have my generic service:

```
public getAll(): Observable<T[]> {
        return this._http.get(this.url, { headers: this.headers })
            .map(this.extractAll)
            .catch((err) => { return this.extractAllError(err, this._alertService); });
}
```

and I am calling the service like this:

```
this._myService.getAll().debounceTime(5000).subscribe((data) => {
            debugger;
            this.data = data;
});
```

but it doesn't wait 5 seconds for me to retrieve the data, it's just instantly.

I've tried with `distinctUntilChanged()` also but same result.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `debounceTime` is not supposed to be used for what you are trying to do here. From the [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html):

> Discard emitted values that take less than the specified time between output

I think what you are looking for is [delay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html):

> Delay emitted values by given time.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think `debounceTime` is a way to control back pressure. Meaning if the request is executed a lot, you will only get a new value when nothing is pushed 5s.

Maybe `throttleTime` is what you're looking for? https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttletime.html

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian I was actually looking for delay. really appreciated :)